# Collating IRC archives into a corpus for text mining

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

Assume I want to do text mining on IRC archived, and want to parse the corpus by months and years, using an archive such as [this one](http://donttreadonme.co.uk/rubinius/index.html) as the source.

In R, what would the overall strategy be for approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scraping part here's some starter code.

```
library(XML)

rootUri <- "http://donttreadonme.co.uk"

doc <- htmlParse(paste0(rootUri, "/rubinius/index.html"))

links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")

links <- grep("rubinius/2014", links, value = TRUE)
links <- gsub("..", "", links, fixed = TRUE)

messages <- lapply(links[1:5], function(l) {
    doc <- htmlParse(paste0(rootUri, l))
    readHTMLTable(doc, which = 1, header = FALSE)
})

messages <- do.call(rbind, messages)

##              V1            V2
## href.1 00:33:57     travis-ci
## href.2 05:04:23     travis-ci
## href.3 05:27:44     travis-ci
## href.4 10:00:59 yorickpeterse
## href.5 13:23:36 yorickpeterse
## href.6 13:23:53 yorickpeterse
##                                                                                          V3
## href.1     [travis-ci] rubinius/rubinius/master (fcc5b8c - Brian Shirai): The build passed.
## href.2 [travis-ci] rubinius/rubinius/master (901a6bc - Brian Shirai): The build was broken.
## href.3  [travis-ci] rubinius/rubinius/master (5cffe7b - Brian Shirai): The build was fixed.
## href.4                                                                              morning
## href.5           oh RubyGems, why do you need the ext builder during runtime?
## href.6                                this better not be because I forgot --rubygems ignore
```